# Assign a Static IP Address to a VirtualBox Guest with a NAT Network Without Accessing the Guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dhcp, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-18.04

I am using VirtualBox 5.2.18 on Ubuntu Server 18.04. I have several VirtualBox guests machines sharing a NAT Network `intnet`. Currently, `intnet` has a DHCP server (set up by VirtualBox) that automatically assigns dynamic IP's to the guests. This works fine, but I would like the DHCP server to assign static IP's to specific guests based on their network interface's MAC address. Static IP's can be set inside the guests, but that takes time and is guest OS dependent. Is there a way, in VirtualBox, to assign static IP's to the guests?

There is a an executable in the VirtualBox installation folder called `VBoxNetDHCP`. Judging by the output of `VBoxNetDHCP`, it seems to allow for static IP assignment by MAC address. I cannot get it to work though, and documentation for it is virtually nonexistent.

Comment: When I do this I use another small VM to provide DHCP, DNS for a fake domain, etc. to my internal network.  Using Debian 9 you can go as low as 128mb of ram and perhaps 1.5gb of disk use after install.

Comment: I'm leaning towards doing that, @ivanivan. Do you happen to have a tutorial at hand?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, give me a few ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when I do things like this (and I do it a lot) I tend to use a VM acting as a network server that does things like DHCP, DNS - both caching for the world and locally spoofing `fake.tld` - etc.

Simplest way is to do a base, bare install of Debian via the netinstall image - select none of the package groups other than the ssh server option and perhaps "standard utilities".

Once it is up and running, to turn it into a DHCP server for your internal VM network, install the `isc-dhcp-server` package.  Then edit `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

Here's a simple example from mine.  This sets a short lease time (5 minutes), sets the client search-domain, etc. to "fake.tld", points their dns queries to 192.168.1.2, and gives out addresses in the range of 10.99.98.80-100 with 24 bits of netmask.  Note that the VM doing this must have an adapter configured with an IP within the 10.99.98.0/24 subnet.

In addition to the general pool, I give the device with the MAC address of `80:c1:6e:2b:b6:cd` an explicitly defined lease (as well as any other `option` like a DNS server to use, gateway, etc) for the `.110` ip.  Any such "static leases" must be for addresses OUTSIDE of your dynamic range, but within the subnet configured in both the config file AND on the network adapter of the machine hosting the service.

When you add a new host and you want it to have a specific IP, simply add another host stanza - the host name doesn't need to match whatever the client sends but it does need to be unique in the file.  After you've added it, restart the service `service isc-dhcp-server restart`

```
ddns-update-style none;
option domain-name "fake.tld";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.2;
option domain-search "fake.tld";
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 720;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;

subnet 10.99.98.0 netmask 255.255.255.0{
    range 10.99.98.80 10.99.98.100;
    option routers 10.99.98.1;
}

host lr-tv {
    hardware ethernet 80:c1:6e:2b:b6:cd;
    fixed-address 10.99.98.110;
    option routers 10.99.98.1;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.2;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, except that: 
1. My DHCP VM uses `Ubuntu Server` (which is based on `Debian`) rather than `Debian`. I installed the same `isc-dhcp-server` package. 
2. My internal network (`intnet` in my question) is `192.168.1.0/24`, and I used  `option routers 192.168.1.1;` and `option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;`. I was able to tell which IP to use by using `nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24`.
3. I defined the options `routers` and `domain-name-servers` globally by adding them to `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` after the line `# option definitions common to all supported networks...`.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in the internal VBOX DHCP server:

1.- FindOut network name for dhcp server:

```
./VBoxManage list dhcpservers
NetworkName:    HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
Dhcpd IP:       192.168.56.100
LowerIPAddress: 192.168.56.101
UpperIPAddress: 192.168.56.254
NetworkMask:    255.255.255.0
Enabled:        Yes
Global Configuration:
    minLeaseTime:     default
    defaultLeaseTime: default
    maxLeaseTime:     default
    Forced options:   None
    Suppressed opts.: None
        1/legacy: 255.255.255.0
Groups:               None
Individual Config:
```

2.- You need also the mac address of your VM's interface

```
PS C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> ./VBoxManage list vms
"accadev-ubuntu20.04" {2a98947e-4b8c-4bc3-9441-2b556d0b33a1}
"accadev-ansible01" {1d261714-9b49-47e2-a634-bc0677f5b707}

PS C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> ./VBoxManage showvminfo accadev-ubuntu20.04 | Select-String -Pattern 'MAC'

NIC 1:                       MAC: 0800275452FB, Attachment: NAT, Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82543GC, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 2:                       MAC: 08002703E954, Attachment: Host-only Interface 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
```

3.- Setup Static Lease for that MAC.

`./VBoxManage dhcpserver modify --ifname "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" --mac-address=08:00:27:f8:31:fa --fixed-address=192.168.56.20`

4.- Restart DHCP server to apply changes

`./VBoxManage dhcpserver restart --ifname "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"`

And that's it. You can do it not only for host-only networks but for any Vbox network with an DHCP server attached

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/vboxmanage-dhcpserver.html)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an addition DHCP Server software, with NAT Network `intnet`, we can setup VirtualBox dhcpserver

```
VBoxManage dhcpserver add --netname intnet --ip 10.13.13.100 --netmask 255.255.255.0 --lowerip 10.13.13.101 --upperip 10.13.13.254 --enable
```

Copy guest MAC address from Settings as seen in screenshot

[image]

Within our dhcpserver, lets add an `Individual Config` section

```
VBoxManage dhcpserver modify --netname intnet --mac-address=080027D23E28 --fixed-address=10.13.13.254
```

P.S. I remember the dhcpserver failed to assign the first IP address of our subset's range, then I tried last IP and it worked, since then I only use the last IP as static.

Reboot or Start your Guest VM

On a Linux based Guest, you can check if DHCP assigned an IP, such as from terminal

```
$ ip a
```

If you do not see an IP released, you need to edit the adapter config file, such as

```
$ nano|vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-[ethN|enp0sN]
```

Usually adding `ONBOOT=yes` fixes this issue,
and off course one of reboots `systemctl restart network` `systemctl restart network.service` , `shutdown -h now` , `reboot now` :)